# Count the frequency that a value occurs in a dataframe (multiple column)

Tags: python, pandas

I want to count the frequency of a value that are same in 2 column, also adding a column at the end that display the counting number & delete the first cloumn.

The dataframe I have

```
| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| -------- | -------- | -------- |
| Column A | Cat      | Fish     |
| Column A | Cat      | Apple    |
| Column A | Cat      | Apple    |
| Column A | Dog      | Lemon    |
| Column A | Dog      | Fish     |
| Column A | Dog      | Fish     |
```

The expected outcome is like

```
| Column A | Column B | Column C | 
| -------- | -------- | -------- | 
| Cat      | Fish     |     1    |
| Cat      | Apple    |     2    |
| Dog      | Lemon    |     1    |
| Dog      | Fish     |     2    |
```

I have tried the

```
df['Column B'].value_counts()
```

But I don't know to handle 2 cloumn at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`GroupBy.count`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.count.html) :

```
out = (
        df.groupby(["Column B", "Column C"],
                   as_index=False, sort=False)
        ["Column A"].count()
       )
```

##### # Output :

```
print(out)
     Column B    Column C  Column A
0   Cat         Fish              1
1   Cat         Apple             2
2   Dog         Lemon             1
3   Dog         Fish              2
```